# Find First Unique Number

Tags: c#, unique

I recently took a Codility test and the question was to find the first unique number in a numeric sequence.  Although I get the correct result using LINQ, it is apparently too expensive computationally and not scalable enough.

How would I improve my solution?

```
var a = new int[] {1, 2, -3, 4, 5, -6, 0, 8, 9, 1, 2};
const int expected = -3;            
var retVal = -1;
var y = a.GroupBy(z => z).Where(z => z.Count() == 1).Select(z => z.Key).ToList();
if (y.Count > 0) retVal = y[0];

Console.Write(retVal==expected);
```

Comment: Wouldn't be better in [CodeReview.SE]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to test the various answers posted above and count the number of ticks using the StopWatch class.

Changing y.Count > 0 to y.Any() resulted in the second lowest tick count, but the largest reduction belongs to the group by comment from Baldrick

To get the average each test was run 50 times.

```
 Ticks
   Min   Max     Avg  Actual
    2  14502     584  -3     Original
    2    919      40  -3     if (y.Any()) actual = y[0];
    2   1423      60  -3     a.GroupBy(g => g).Where(w => w.Count() == 1)
                                            .Select(s => s.Key)
                                            .FirstOrDefault();
    2   1553      65  -3     a.ToLookup(i => i).First(i => i.Count() == 1).Key;
    2    317      15  -3     a.GroupBy(i => i).First(i => i.Count() == 1).Key;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
var result = a.ToLookup(i => i).First(i => i.Count() == 1).Key;
```

This should give -3.

It builds a `Lookup` object with a key created using each number in the list, and a value of the same number.

In the case of duplicates, then multiple entries are created under each key. The first unique value will be the first group in the `Lookup` with one entry.

(You could just as easily use `GroupBy`, instead of `ToLookup`. The end result will be the same.)

Comment: can you explain a bit?

Comment: I don't think `ToLookup` is significantly different here, but there is a big improvement in not calling `ToList` or `Count` on the outer result.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    var result = a.GroupBy(g => g).Where(w => w.Count() == 1).Select(s => s.Key).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: this will throw NullReferenceException if there is no group with 1 element

Comment: @ad1Dima i know your are right - just an example - iv edited my code